# Kanji that represent "Death before Dishonor" meaning

Tags: kanji

There's a saying in English "Death before Dishonor"

Which means : To die before dishonoring what ever holds great value/ You will die before going against anything that you believe in or die before you sell out/ To die before you dishonor your gang or hood

Its also a name of a band.

> The questions is... what is the best kanji to represent this English saying of "Death before Dishonor" ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's **玉砕{ぎょくさい}**. It's literal meaning is **to shatter like a pearl**, and the real meaning is to die rather than to surrender (= *Death before Dishonor*). This was the word often used to indicate the Japanese army has annihilated (instead of being taken captive) at Pacific war.

I also found more about [玉砕](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8E%89%E7%A0%95) on Wikipedia...

The origin of this word is from this Chinese writing:

> 大丈夫寧可**玉砕**何能**瓦全**
>   A great man should die with a good grace - rather than surviving like **an intact tile**, you should die like **a shattered pearl**.

---

Sidenote: So... what is the antonym?
It's 瓦全{がぜん}.